# Use dimension when creating measure with Case statement in Looker

Tags: group-by, case, dimensions, measure, looker

I am trying to create a measure conditionally based on a dimension.

My dimensions:

```
dimension_group: date {
    hidden: yes
    type: time
    timeframes: [
      raw,
      date,
      week,
      month,
      quarter,
      year
    ]
    convert_tz: no
    datatype: date
    sql: ${TABLE}.date ;;
  }
```

```
dimension: status {
    type: string
    sql: CASE
          WHEN UPPER(${TABLE}.status) ='APPROVED' THEN 'Approved'
          WHEN UPPER(${TABLE}.status) ='PENDING' THEN 'Pending'
        END;;
  }
```

My Measures:

```
measure: xyz {    
    type: sum
    value_format: "$#,##0.00"
    sql: ${TABLE}.xyz ;;
  }
```

```
measure: abc {    
    type: sum
    value_format: "$#,##0.00"
    sql: ${TABLE}.abc ;;
  }
```

Measure with conditions:

```
measure: conditional {
    type: number
    value_format: "$#,##0.00"
    sql: CASE WHEN ${status} = 'Pending' THEN ${xyz}
         ELSE ${abc}
         END;;
  }
```

On my Explore, when I select `date` and `conditional`.  I keep getting the error:

ERROR: column "table.status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I understand what the error is. I am just not sure how to fix this. How do I resolve this error? I need all the dimensions and measures.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dimension `conditional`:

```
dimension: conditional {
    type: number
    value_format: "$#,##0.00"
    sql: CASE WHEN ${status} = 'Pending' THEN ${xyz}
        ELSE ${abc}
        END;;
}
```

And then create a measure `sum_conditional` on that dimension:

```
measure: sum_conditional {
    type: sum
    value_format: "$#,##0.00"
    sql: ${conditional};;
  }
```